# How to convert json key in lower case in php

Tags: php, json

How to convert json key in lower case in php,

For example :

```
"Object" : {
            "objectType" : "Activity",
            "id" : "http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/page",
            "Definition" : {
                "name" : {
                    "en-US" : "What Is Information Security?"
                },
                "Description" : {
                    "en-US" : ""
                }
            }
        }
```

Above data should be look like :

```
"object" : {
            "objecttype" : "Activity",
            "id" : "http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/page",
            "definition" : {
                "name" : {
                    "en-us" : "What Is Information Security?"
                },
                "description" : {
                    "en-us" : ""
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe just use lowercase names to generate that JSON?

Comment: This would  help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php

Answer (score 2):

your json code is invalid. you have to wrap it with "{" and "}"

check `array_change_key_case()` function at http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-change-key-case.php

Here is the solution you are looking for.

```
// Your input json wrapped with "{" and "}"
$json = '{ "Object" : { "objectType" : "Activity", "id" : "http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/page", "Definition" : { "name" : { "en-US" : "What Is Information Security?" }, "Description" : { "en-US" : "" } } } }';

// json_decode() converts json to array
$array = json_decode($json, true);

// key case changer. changes key recursively
// Source php.net
function array_change_key_case_recursive($arr)
{
    return array_map(function($item){
        if(is_array($item))
            $item = array_change_key_case_recursive($item);
        return $item;
    },array_change_key_case($arr));
}


$new_array = array_change_key_case_recursive($array);

// You expected json output
$new_json = json_encode($new_array);

echo $new_json;
```

Answer (score 0):

$json = json_decode(json_encode( array_combine(array_map('strtolower', array_keys($json)), $json) ));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).